# Slice list backwards from index 0 in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following list:

```
the_list = ['one','two','three','four','five']
```

How can I slice this python list so that my output is the following (print order does not matter):

```
'one','five','four'
```

I essentially want to start at index 0 and then slice backwards

Thanks!

Comment: Slicing of lists has no "wraparound", you can slice forward, backward, and every *k*-th element, but not a wrap around (both forward and backward), you thus will need to perform two slices and "append" subslices.

Comment: Ah that is unfortunate, thank you for clarifying however!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
the_list[0:1] + the_list[-1:2:-1]
```

This adds 2 list, where your second list starts from the last element, takes the step size of 2 and in reverse. You can't do multiple slicing but you can select what items to add on or be appended.

Comment: You should also note that this method applies specifically to your sample list. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could append your first element at the end of the list, and then slice backwards, excluding the first element:

`the_list.append(the_list[0])
[the_list[-i] for i in range(1,len(the_list))]`